# How can i update an array of objects on each iteration to add a new given object on that array if the object.name property isn't included else update

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to make a function that does the job of a POS billing section. when an item is clicked to grab and pass the values of an item (name, price, qty ...) to into an object and then the object is passed into the function as an argument. each item should exist only once and if the same item is clicked more than once it should only update the value of the "qty" propertiy by 1 and keep the track. i'm storing all he objects in an array called totalItems. i'm stuck at the qty value updating part it's crashing and getting different kind of issues. please help .

```
// THIS ARE THE OBJECT PROPERTIES 
// {
//     img: '',
//     name: '',
//     price: 0,
//     qty: 1
// }

let totalItems = []

const sumTotalItems = (obj) => {
    if (totalItems.length) {
        totalItems.map((item) => {
           if (obj.name === item.name) {
            const index = totalItems.indexOf(item)
            const newItem = item = {...item, qty: item.qty += 1}
            const updatedArray = totalItems.splice(index, 1, newItem)
            return totalItems = [...updatedArray]
           } else {
            return totalItems = [...totalItems, obj]
           }
        })
    } else {
        return totalItems = [obj]     
    }
    console.log(totalItems)
}
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how map works. What you need here is something else.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let totalItems = []

const sumTotalItems = (obj) => {
    const currentIndex = totalItems.findIndex((item) => item.name === obj.name)
    if (currentIndex >= 0) {
        totalItems[currentIndex].qty += 1
    } else {
        totalItems.push({...obj, qty: 1})
    }
    console.log(totalItems)
}

sumTotalItems({name: 'a'})
sumTotalItems({name: 'b'})
sumTotalItems({name: 'a'})
sumTotalItems({name: 'c'})
sumTotalItems({name: 'b'})
sumTotalItems({name: 'c'})
```

Comment: Ok well i tried this one and it seems to be working but as i see the thing that was stopping me was if (totalItems.length) instead of if (currentIndex >= 0). Can you enlighten for me just this point why this works better than .length ?

Comment: `totalItems.length` when used in if is a int cast to bool meaning it will be true for all values but 0, so your if is only checking if there is any value in the array. My if is checking if the value we are looking for is in the array (currentIndex will be -1 when not found).
Please accept and upvote my answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```js
let totalItems = []

const addItem = ( item) => {
  const items = totalItems.reduce((res, i) => {
    return {
     ...res,
     [i.name]: i
    }  
    }, {}) 
   
   const existing = items[item.name] || {...item, qty: 0}
   existing.qty += item.qty
   
   items[item.name] = existing
   
   return Object.values(items)
}
const item1 = {
  img: 'img1',
  name: 'item1',
  price: 1,
  qty: 1
}

const item2 = {
  img: 'img2',
  name: 'item2',
  price: 2,
  qty: 2
}

totalItems = addItem(item1)
console.log(totalItems)


totalItems = addItem(item1)
console.log(totalItems)

totalItems = addItem(item1)
console.log(totalItems)


totalItems = addItem(item2)
console.log(totalItems)
```